# How do I store a 64-bit integer as a binary value, and I how do I read a stored 64-bit integer?

Tags: php, binary, integer, 64-bit

I want to convert 64bits binary value to integer or string and vice versa.

I know that I can use pack("J*",...) and unpack("J*",...) for my work.

but it only works in php v5.6 and later and my php version is 5.4

now how do this in php v5.4 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, by saving it as two 32-bit values:

```
$high   = ($value & 0xffffffff00000000) >> 32; 
$low    = $value & 0x00000000ffffffff; 
$packed = pack('NN', $high, $low); 

list($high, $low) = array_values(unpack('N2', $packed)); 
$value            = $high << 32 | $low;
```